# How to create this kind of spin animation?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

How to make this kind of spin animation?

https://www.google.com/search?q=animated+tabbar+designs&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN892IN892&sxsrf=ALeKk037iypRghZhFJ7-cacTAuLpXV5p-g:1609232185076&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjiloKG6fLtAhWbXCsKHShlCiQQ_AUoAXoECAcQAw&biw=1536&bih=754#imgrc=pXQFRx4PCJK3rM

I have done animation of rotation like shown below:

slide_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

MainActivity

```
val r = RotateAnimation(
                    30.0f,
                    90.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                    0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                    0.5f
                )
                r.duration = 500
                r.repeatCount = 0
                binding.llHome.startAnimation(r)
```

But this is not coming properly as needed in link given above, so someone please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Please reply to this